# How to ask a question regarding a concept without getting closed?

Tags: discussion

Every time I try to ask as question regarding programming concepts, I am voted to get closed. Why? I thought that is what the tag `language-concept` e.g. is all about. How do I ask a question regarding concepts without getting closed?

Comment: You might have just called the [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) upon yourself...

Comment: I think the comments in your example question sufficiently explain why it was closed. "I want to understand the concepts" it's not something we can help you with, I'm afraid. You need to be a lot more specific than that.

Comment: The first linked question would require a book to answer so it's really too broad. Arguably, I'd limit the question to ONE concept at a time, explaining what you DO understand about and why you're having trouble applying it to a specific issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Why? The meta effect would apply if I had posted in say, meta.datascience.stackexchange, but I stayed in the stackoverflow domain.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Well, I'd except an answer linking to a book.

Comment: Well, questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Indeed, linking to a book is the definition of an off-site resource.

Comment: You posted on Meta about a SO question, which draws more attention to the SO question. That's the idea behind the meta effect.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: So, basically stackoverflow is not suitable to get started in a topic, right? Because any such a question would be "too broad" or would require a recommendation how to get started which is opinionated...

Comment: @Cerbrus: Are we not supposed to give examples?

Comment: Please read [What is the Meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: Happy now ?  ;-)

Comment: You can make any question stackable you just have to really know what you are doing.

Comment: I never told you to remove the link. I just wanted to warn you of the possibility of more votes on the linked question.

Comment: @kpie: Obviously I don't and the "community" has not been really helpful so far regarding this aspect.

Comment: Depends what you mean by getting started. If question is give me the code, write me the book or similar then it is off-topic (too broad) question, too. Ask one question at the time, be specific. Add code and examples that will help illustrating concepts and parts you don't understand well.

Comment: I can't imagine that anyone in the 'community' desires to spend hours/days providing free tuition:(

Comment: @kpie: This question is the best example: I don't get how to ask good questions, so I ask, and the very question, about how to improve my questions gets downvoted...

Comment: Maybe because you had to ask a meta question to explain why 'provide extensive, personal and free language tuition' was not well-received.

Comment: Your question here suggests that you haven't thoroughly read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so it shows lack of research.

Comment: @Make42 There's a lot of literature, easy to find, that tells you how to ask good questions. Don't try to put that burden on members of the community, who only have a finite amount of time to help, and want to spend that time answering questions that are already good. That's why we come here, after all.

Comment: @Make42 one thing that is unfortunate: at the scale Stack operates now, new users can't be expected to get the rules (both written in the help center and the ones discussed on the meta site) without having to search for them. There is simply too many new users for the amount of old ones. It's a reality of the site: if you want to get a good reception, the onus will be on you to read, lurk around meta, get acquainted by osmosis. You may get someone who will take the time to explain everything, and that's great. You can't feel entitled to having that, though

Comment: If I were in your situation, I would... 1) Go to amazon and search for books about R 2) rank by rating 3) read reviews for the top 3 4) buy two of them 5) read 6) if I'm still confused about a number of things, I'd pick the number one confusing item, and ask a question about it.  I'd describe what I think I know, and why I believe I'm incorrect or unclear.

Answer (score 7):

In general, people look for a few points about a question:

1. What someone is trying to do.
2. What they have tried.
3. What feedback the execution environment has provided.

When you ask something regarding a concept, let's take for this example `R keywords`, if you don't make a question specific enough to necessitate a person's time to provide a unique solution, the process of Stack users regurgitating info from the might offend people.

With that said, if you make sure to make your questions specific enough to merit there being here (and not in a Google search), they shouldn't get down voted so hard.

So lets look at your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791521/understanding-rs-deep-basics:

Now first the title. The title indicates that you might be writing some crazy test code to reveal the languages insides... This isn't a newspaper and we ought to strive for functional titles, not flashy ones. You are pretty much just asking for a best reference and a bunch of terms you want to look up, so ask about the fastest way to get information about R-keywords. I don't want to start edit wars, but I know there are some nifty hotkeys in RStudio, and many languages include functions that allow for keywords to provide information about themselves, so ask for that. People don't want to do the research for you, but everyone is glad to share their resources and answer specific questions, especially when people all-ready walked the path.

If a question is too general, people can't know what experiences touch on applicable solutions.

Just keep the idea of optimal questions that advance you and your ability to advance yourself in mind, while respecting the time of those who make answers and we will all enjoy the community more.

That said, I have also felt some cold reactions from the community, it's just the nature of the Internet, I guess.

Be specific, and good luck!